# Display Post's Category within Wordpress Loop

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to show the categories in which the post belongs to within my main post's loop. I've had a look through Stackoverflow but the answers seem to not be working or not displaying anything. I'm trying the below:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $cats = wp_get_post_categories($id);
    ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">
                            <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't figure our what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `wp_get_post_categories` returns an array of the term ids. In your `foreach` you are using `$cat->XXX` for the link and the name. However, `$cat` isn't an object. You need one more step.

You need to use `get_category` to get the actual category Object.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $cats = wp_get_post_categories($id);
    ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): 
                        // This is the new line.
                        $cat_object = get_category( $cat );
                     ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_object->cat_ID); ?>">
                            <?php echo $cat_object->name; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```